# Display images with cdvfile://* in img tag cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, cordova-plugin-camera

I'm using the cordova-plugin-camera to take a picture with these options:

```
quality: 100,
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
sourceType: srcType,
encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
allowEdit: false,
saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
correctOrientation: true
```

This is working and I get an URL / Path like this:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=FBA79210-5E65-4C9B-BF19-9F1169B777C0&ext=JPG
```

Then, I want to convert this path to a cdvfile:// to display the image in an  tag.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI, function(fileEntry) {
        const url = fileEntry.toInternalURL()
})
```

This is also working and I get:

```
cdvfile://localhost/assets-library/asset/asset.JPG?id=FBA79210-5E65-4C9B-BF19-9F1169B777C0&ext=JPG
```

But the image is not rendered. I tried to add `<access origin="cdvfile:*" />` in my config.xml but that's not working either. How can i get a valid path / url to display the image?

Best wishes,
Joeri

Comment: any luck with that? I was also trying to load the DATA_URL with readAsDataURL (File plugin) but had no success with path or file parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it with a different approach. After getting the `cdvfile` url I used [Photo Library plugin](https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library) to get the blob file through the `getPhoto` method passing the `id` present in the `cdvfile` url and with this in hand I got the `img` source working with the `base64data` as below:

```
photoLibrary.getPhoto('FBA79210-5E65-4C9B-BF19-9F1169B777C0').then((blob)=>{

   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
   reader.onloadend = function() {
      var base64data = reader.result;                
      img.src = base64data;
   }
});
```

**UPDATE** 
You can also use `getThumbnail` function to improve your page loading depending on the quality, size and quantity of photos you app is supposed to handle.